# Google OAuth: No refresh_token

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/Nyholm/google-api-php-client) to upload videos to Youtube.

Since I need access to only one Youtube channel, not to many users channels, I have to authorize  my app one time and store a `refresh_token` to achieve a not expiring access to the API.

The problem is that I don't get a `refresh_token` with the `$client->getAccessToken()`-call.
I only get the following values: token_type, expires_in, id_token, created

I created a "Client ID for web applications" using Google Console and use the following code:

```
<?php
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '<my client id>';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '<my client secret>';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('<my app name>');
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setState('offline');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    var_dump($accessToken, json_decode($accessToken));
}
else {
    $aurl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $aurl = str_replace('approval_prompt=auto', 'approval_prompt=force', $aurl);
    echo '<a href="'.$aurl.'">'.$aurl.'</a>';
}
```

As you can see I already use `$client->setState('offline')` and insert `apprival_prompt=force` in the authURL.

I also tried to revoke access in my Google account manager multiple times and created a new API project.

Thank you in advance for telling me what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();` is a post.

```
client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

It needs to be posted to Google.  When it comes back you should have `$_SESSION['token']`

Full Untested Example:

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    }


 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

Something like this maybe. Sorry I cant test it from here its an edit from some other code. If it doesn't work let me know and I will try and test it tonight.

Comment: Thank you!

Unfortunately I also don't get a `refresh_token` using your example code.

Comment: does it pop up asking you to authorize it?  Did you change the Redirect URI to yours and not mine?  remember it must be the redirect URi you have set for the application.

Comment: Yes, i could authorize using the example. Everything works fine, I just don't get the `refresh_token`

Comment: $_SESSION['token'] should be your refreshToken

Comment: `$_SESSION['token']` is the full json object including `"access_token":"...","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"created":1400763451`.

I think `refresh_token` should by one item in this json string

Comment: I will have to look at it when I get home.  Try Digging around in  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php  Its there we just have to find it :)